# Option to change language in an android app

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android app where i have a settings activity.
In this settings Activity, I have a ListPreference with 3 values, each for a language.

I would like to get the value selected by the user and then change the language of the application according to the choice of the user

How would you do this guys ?

Thanks for reading and help !

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Answer (score 0):

The link in the comments above is the complete answer, but just to get you started, to support whatever language the user's device is set to, you need to extract all of the text in your app that will be visible on screen out to a 'strings.xml' file.  Then translate all of the strings in that file into a separate 'strings.xml' file for each language you wish to support.  This file lives in the res/values folder, and if you wanted to do a Spanish translation, you would create a res/values-es folder, and add a 'strings.xml' file there, with entries that have the same 'name' as the English translation, but with the Spanish translation as the 'value' example:

```
res/values/strings.xml
<string name="change_voter">Change Voter</string>

res/values-es/strings.xml
<string name="change_voter">Cambiar de Votantes</string>

//Then you get the value into your label like so:
tvVoter.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.change_voter));
```

You will also need to consider any graphics (bitmaps, backgrounds, buttons) and if they have words written in the default language, there will need to be copies of those translated into the other language and in another localized folder.